# Microprofile generate Open-Api File on build

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi, microprofile

prior to using Eclipse Microprofile we've generated our open-api files via the `io.openapitools.swagger:swagger-maven-plugin`. 
This plugin relies on the `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations` maven dependency.

Eclipse Microprofile though comes with a different dependency which does not seem to be enough for the openapitools plugin, therfore the generated open-api file does not contain any descriptions and other data provided within the annotations.

Does you know a way to generate an open-api definition file using the microprofile dependencies?

The following is the configuration for the openapitools swagger plugin.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.openapitools.swagger</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <useResourcePackagesChildren>true</useResourcePackagesChildren>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/open-api/</outputDirectory>
            <outputFormats>JSON,YAML</outputFormats>
            <prettyPrint>false</prettyPrint>

            <resourcePackages>
                <resourcePackage>...</resourcePackage>
            </resourcePackages>
            <outputFilename>...</outputFilename>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've found so far is a plugin that the [Apache Geronimo](https://geronimo.apache.org/) project created: [Geronimo OpenAPI Maven plugin](https://github.com/apache/geronimo-openapi). The example on their GitHub page shows how to use it.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.geronimo</groupId>
  <artifactId>geronimo-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${openapi.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-openapi.json</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>openapi.json</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <application>com.test.MyApp</application>
        <endpointClasses>
          <endpointClass>com.test.SomeEndpoint</endpointClass>
          <endpointClass>com.test.SomeOtherEndpoint</endpointClass>
        </endpointClasses>
        <info>
          <version>1</version>
          <title>My Title</title>
          <description>Bla Bla</description>
        </info>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://geronimo.apache.org/microprofile/openapi.html) is rather thin.  Based on the dependencies list, it looks like it also supports YAML format.